# Burned wire in breaker box replaced, did this likely solve the problem?

Tags: electrical

I am in a country where the standards and compliance to code aren't nearly as high as the US.  The lights suddenly started flickering when the hot water heater was working hard (when the shower was on).  I checked the breaker box and it was sparking.

The electrician said the breaker was old and showed me the wire from the supply side of one of the breakers, and the insulation had melted somewhat and was discolored.  He replaced this with similar or the same gauge wire and put in a new breaker.  I noticed that this breaker had a larger tolerance than the first one (25A vs. 16A).

This building does not have a ground connection, just neutral and hot.

Presumably if I was pulling too much current the breakers would flip before the supply-side wire began to melt and spark.  But of course it's possible there were oversized breakers installed here anyway.

I can monitor my circuit power with home automation tools and I see that I normally pull well below what the breakers can handle.  The only time they trip is when the dishwasher heater is on.

Should I be concerned?

Comment: Breaker size must match wire gauge for protection.  In the US this would mean a 15 amp breaker must at minimum have 14 gauge wire(or larger).  Common hot water tanks will have 30 amp breaker and 10 gauge wire(US).  Sparks/melting wires can be caused by too much power/amps and/or loose connections.  Loose connections about 80% or more, too much power the rest usually(my guess).  Check the wire size to the breaker size and check for loose connections.

Comment: Do you have an electric shower head water heater or do you have a tankless electric water heater on or in the wall or do you have an electric hot water tank?

Comment: @JimStewart A small tank mounted to the wall in another room, that heats water for the entire apartment

Comment: Putting in a larger breaker on a circuit is 99.9% bad.  0.1% of the time the circuit has large enough wire gauge to handle it.

Comment: @crip659 Yep.  I'm not even really worried about what's inside my apartment since I don't draw a huge amount.  I'm more wondering about from the breaker box upstream toward the provider (apartment building wiring)

Comment: It is not about how much power you use normally on the circuit, it is what happens when stuff goes wrong.  A bigger breaker is okay when everything is good, it is when stuff wrong and the big breaker does not trip and the wires start to burn up inside of your walls.

Comment: @crip659 I agree there too.  Since the wire melted before the breaker I am questioning the adequacy of the wiring before my box.  But very true now that a larger breaker is installed (25A, 220V, which I think is still relatively low?) I need to keep an eye out

Comment: The American line of thinking, based on fairly recent science, is that burned up wires at terminals are generally caused by improper screw torque.  Other science proved master electricians do not have calibrated arms (they couldn't hit hit a torque any more accurately than their spouse or business manager could; this was tested at trade shows.)  So they bang the drum pretty hard on the "use a torque screwdriver" concept in the States.

Comment: When we moved into our house in 1978 I found a flickering light in a hall was caused by a loose neutral at the neutral connection in the panel. It burned the insulation,  damaged the #12 aluminum wire. Cut off the damaged wire and reinserted but found the connection screws in the neutral bar could not make tight connection with #12 aluminum. Pigrtailed all the neutrals with copper and have had no more trouble. The connections at the breakers were all OK so no pigtails there.